# Why scrollbar doesn't want to work with Label?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, scrollbar

```
win = Tk()

win.title("Курс валют в рублях по данным ЦБ РФ")
win.geometry('445x200+200+100')
win.resizable(False, False)

frame = Frame(win)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

canvas = Canvas(frame)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient = VERTICAL)
scroll.config(command = canvas.yview)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)

lab1 = Label(canvas, text = "Курс валют в рублях по данным Центрального Банка Российской Федерации")
lab1.configure(text= xw + xe + xr + xt + xy + xu + xi + xo + xp + xa + xs + xd + xf  + xg + xh + xj + xk + xl + xz + xx + xc + xv + xb + xn + xm + xqq + xqw + xqe + xqr + xqt + xqy + xqu + xq)
lab1.pack()

but1 = tk.Button(canvas, text="Список всех валют с их курсами", command=but1click)
but2 = tk.Button(canvas, text="Перевод с иностранной валюты в рубли", command=but2click)
but1.pack(side = "right")
but2.pack(side = "left")

win.mainloop()
```

This is just part of my code

I tried to make somehow from Label to Text, but I couldn't do it. Can you help me please to add scrollbar here?

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. It's not clear what problem you're currently experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can only scroll canvas items, not widgets added to a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. If you want the label to scroll, you must add it to the canvas with `create_window`.